# Is it a good bison practice to not have semantic values, but use side effects of actions?

Tags: parsing, bison

I have a language where the semantic meaning of everything, is an array of characters, or array of arrays.  So I have the following YYSTYPE:

```
typedef struct _array {
    union {
        char *chars; // start of string
        void *base;  // start of array
    };
    unsigned n;      // number of valid elements in above
    unsigned allocated;  // number of allocated elements for above
} array;

#define YYSTYPE array
```

and I can append an array of characters to an array of arrays with

```
void append(YYSTYPE *parray, YYSTYPE *string);
```

Suppose the grammar (SSCCE) is:

```
%token  WORD
%%
array       :       WORD    
            | array WORD    
            ;
```

So I accept a sequence of words.  For each word, the semantic value becomes that array of characters, and then I would like to append each of these, to the array of arrays, for the whole sequence.

There are several possible ways to design the actions:

1. Have `array` symbol have the semantic value of type `array`.  If I do this, then the action for `array WORD` will have to copy the array `$1` to `$$` which is slow, so I don't like that.
2. Have `array` symbol have the semantic value of type `array *`.  Now the action for `array WORD`, I can just add to the array `*$1` and then set `$$` to be equal to `$1`.  But I don't like this for two reasons. First, the semantic meaning is not a pointer to `array`, it is the `array`.  Second, for the action for the rule `array : WORD`, I will have to `malloc` the structure, which is slow.  Yes, the 'append' sometimes does a `malloc`, but if I allocate enough, not frequently.  I want to avoid any unnecessary `malloc` for performance reasons.
3. Forget about trying to have a semantic value for the symbol `array` at all, and use globals:

   `static YYSTYPE g_array;`

   `YYSTYPE *g_parray = &g_array;`

and then, the actions will just use

```
append(g_parray, word_array)
```

The way the whole grammar works, I don't need more than one `g_array`.  The above is the fastest I can think of.  But it is really bad design - lots of globals, no semantic values, instead, everything happens by side effects to globals.

So, personally I don't like any of them.  Which is the commonly accepted best practice for bison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, there is no point in using globals. More-or-less modern versions of bison have the `%parse-param` directive, which allows you to have a sort of 'parsing context'. The context may take care of all memory allocations etc.

It may reflect the current parsing state - i. e. have the notion of 'current `array`' etc. In this case, your semantic actions can rely on context knowing where you are.

```
%{
    typedef struct tagContext Context;
    typedef struct tagCharString CharString;

    void start_words(Context* ctx);
    void add_word(Context* ctx, CharString* word);
%}

%union {
    CharString* word;
}
%parse-param {Context* ctx}

%token<word> WORD
%start words

%%

words
    : { start_words(ctx); } word
    | words                 word
    ;

word
    : WORD { add_word(ctx, $1); }
    ;
```

If you *only* parse a list of words and nothing else, you can make *it* your context.

However, in a simple grammar, it is much clearer if you pass information through `YYSTYPE`:

```
%{
    typedef struct tagContext Context;
    typedef struct tagCharString CharString;
    typedef struct tagWordList WordList;

    // word_list = NULL to start a new list
    WordList* add_word(Context* ctx, WordList* prefix, CharString* word);
%}

%union {
    CharString* word;
    WordList* word_list;
}
%parse-param {Context* ctx}

%token<word> WORD
%type<word_list> words words_opt
%start words

%%

words
    : words_opt WORD { $words = add_word(ctx, $words_opt, $WORD); }
    ;

words_opt
    : %empty { $words_opt = NULL; }
    | words
    ;
```

Performance differences between the two approaches seem to be negligible.

**Memory cleanup**

If your input text is parsed without errors, you are always responsible of cleaning up all dynamic memory. However, if your input text causes parse errors, the parser will have to discard some tokens. There may be two approaches to cleanup in this case.

First, you can keep track of all memory allocations in your context and free them all when destroying the context.

Second, you can rely on bison destructors:

```
%{
    void free_word_list(WordList* word_list);
%}

%destructor { free_word_list($$); } <word_list>
```

Comment: Your first approach is like my third approach, except without globals, and I will take that as my answer, thank you. Your second approach is really the same as my second approach.